# Receber formulário post no NodeJS retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou aprendendo socket.io desenvolvendo um chat e etc. O que acontece é que na página de login que estou criando não estou conseguindo receber os dados dos inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h4>Login</h4>
      <form id="login" method="POST" action="/home">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <small>Ainda não tem uma conta?<a href="register.html">Clique aqui.</a></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

E quando eu tento receber esses valores nas minha rotas ele me retorna undefined:

```
routes.post('/home', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  console.log(username + ": " + password)
  res.render('home.html')
})
```

No meu server.js (que é o arquivo principal) eu estou passando o `app.use(express.json())` e mesmo assim meu único retorno que tenho no meu terminal é:

```
undefined: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os formulários do HTML não enviam os dados no formato JSON. Enviam-nos, por padrão, no formato URL Encoded. Portanto, utilizar o middleware `express.json()` é, no seu caso, um *erro*.

Você deve usar o *middleware* que faça o *parse* do `body` no formato URL Encoded. Assim:

```js
app.use(express. urlencoded());
```

<sup>Consulte a [documentação](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) para saber mais.</sup>

Você também pode usar os dois, se estiver utilizando os dois formatos. Mas creio que não seja o caso.

Comment: Obrigado ainda estou aprendendo. Nunca teria imaginado algo do tipo. Vlw